# Proposal for a Portuguese version of Mathematics SE

Tags: discussion, languages, area51, proposal

There is a proposal for a new Q&A site of Mathematics for Portuguese-speaking users, which form a considerable amount of contributors of this site. I'd really appreciate the support and comments of Lusophone users of Mathematics.SE on this project. Thanks!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87874/mathematics-in-portuguese

Comment: [We will not be able to support sites other than Stack Overflow in other languages for the foreseeable future](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/20138) -- Tim Post, the Community Manager leading the internationalization project.

Comment: Related older post: [About language-specific versions of math.stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16517/about-language-specific-versions-of-math-stackexchange). One of the answers mentioned that proposals for Spanish and Korean math.SE existed at the time. Both proposals seem to be dead by now. [Proposal for Italian language mutation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/italian-language-math-stack-exchange-area-51-proposal) ended in the same way.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Maybe it's not the case for portuguese, because there is already a translation of stackexchange-like websites for portuguese, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @HomegrownTomato And as english is not a wide-spread language in Brazil (the largest portuguese-speaking country), even for colleges students, I really don't see how this site would divert traffic from math se.

Comment: It is the case for Portuguese, too. A well-supported Area 51 proposal for Super User in Portuguese was closed and deleted.

Comment: meta.pt.SO might be also a reasonable place to advertise your proposal and to get some input about its viability. There SU in Portuguese, which was mentioned in the above comment, was also discussed on that site: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367/super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: @Rodrigo: Was it truly necessary to bump a closed question from 5 years ago for some formatting?

Comment: Agreed with @AsafKaragila . This post did not necessitate a bump.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am well aware of how this site works. I've been around for the better part of a decade. Editing a post in meta that is totally dead (in multiple ways) just for some formatting isn't a net positive, regardless of the validity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proposal is now closed. I quote [Tim Post's explanation](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20879/why-was-this-proposal-closed/20943#20943) below.

---

We lack the resources needed to get the site off the ground, and guide it through the early (but most critical) stages. We have a Portuguese speaking community manager, and he doesn't have enough hours in his weeks to get everything done that he'd like for Portuguese SO. There is simply not enough bandwidth to give.

Do we want a Portuguese math site, or Super User, or cooking site? ***Yes, we would love to have these because it would be a major win for us and the Internet in general.*** I just don't know *when* we'll be able to support it on our end.

I'm comfortable saying *definitely* not in the next year, and that's *way* more time than I'm prepared to ask anyone to wait *now that I know how long it's going to take*.

Our *primary* localization strategy surrounds our flagship product, which is Stack Overflow. *That has to come first.* When that dust settles, which is going to take a while, we can begin exploring the idea of launching other sites.